# Cake PHP change value of hidden form item by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I have the below cake php form in my view:

```
<?php $form_id = 'message_form ' + $profile_id ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('id' => $form_id, 'url' => array('app' => true, 'controller' => 'messages', 'action' => 'new', $profile_id))); ?>

     <?php echo $this->Form->input('text', array('type' => 'textarea', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false,  'data-validate' => 'not-empty', 'name' => 'data[Message][content]', 'placeholder' => 'Reply...')); ?>

     <?php echo $this->Form->input('hidden', array('type' => 'hidden', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false,  'name' => 'data[Message][parent_id]', 'value' => 1)); ?>

      <div class="message-reply-options">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></a>&nbsp;
          <a href="#" class="empty-textarea"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>&nbsp;
          <span class="pull-right">
               <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Send', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
          </span>
      </div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

This works fine, however I need to be able to change the hidden fields value via javascript depending on something the user does else where on the page.

Below is my current javascript I am using for this, however it does not change the value (but gives no error either).

```
var newestmessage = response.ChildMessage[response.ChildMessage.length-1];
var parentid =  newestmessage.parent_message_id;
document.getElementsByName('data[Message][parent_id]').value = $parentid;
```

Comment: can you directly tell that on which change you want hidden field value will change,

Comment: Yes, I am sure the change is firing as other javascript is also run

Comment: I don't understand what you tell?

Comment: I know the javascript is run, however the value of the hidden field has not changed after it is run. When I submit the form the default value is still in its place.

Comment: check first that `var parentid` have any value or not by alerting it. and change it to` document.getElementsById('hidden_field').value = $parentid;` also give `id = hidden_field` to your hidden field. thanks

Comment: `parentid` != `$parentid`. If these two are actually ment to be different variables, then you should show the complete code related to `$parentid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This would have probably been a comment, but since I don't have enough reputation...*

I guess you are trying to change/assign the value to hidden field on a particular, action.
I just assume a click event.

Jquery required

```
$('.classNameOfClickableObjt').clilck(function(){
   $('input[name="data[Message][parent_id]"]').val(parentid);
   /*Another alternative, you might assign attribute, like 
      $('input[name="data[Message][parent_id]"]').attr('value', parentid); */
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try jquery and ajax functionally to check the value of hidden input box.

Comment: It's must be a comment not an answer. remove it.

Comment: then don't do that because you will loose more point. if any one suggested that you can vote-up that comment.

Comment: Giving answers worth giving and you will earn the privilege to post comments. This will make you lose points meaning it will take more time to earn the points needed to comment. Your answer doesn't offer a solid solution or have any detail/reference links on how to add/use jQuery or Ajax. **+ jQuery isn't tagged**

Comment: yes you need to save your points so that you will be able to answer as soon as possible. see already you loosed 6 point i think. still if you leave it you will loose more.